# making pictures change on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I have picture links that are stored in a array, and I change the background of a div using those picture links when a button is clicked.

So far everything is ok, but I don't understand how can I make the function return the first value of array ([0]) when the i value is greater than the array.length value.

Here's what I got:

```
function palabifunkcija(){
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').value= ++i;
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').style.background= bildes[i];
    if (i>bildes.length){
        return i=0;
    } 
}
```

Clicking makes the pictures change, but when the if statement executes, i have to click twice on the button and it displays 2nd picture (bildes[1]) not bildes[0].

Can anyone explain why it's so and how can I fix it, so it works properly?

Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the remainder of `i` divided by the array length.

```
var i = 0, 
    length = bildes.length;
function palabifunkcija(){
    i++;
    i %= length;
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').value = i;
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').style.background = bildes[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Now I just have understand how it works.

Comment: It always 'normalizes' current index by total length preventing it to be larger than length. Suppose length is 3; 0%3 == 0, 1%3 == 1, 2%3 == 2, 3%3 == 0 etc

Comment: I still don't understand how it works. From what I understand- it devides the 2 numbers and shows what's left. I guess that's not the case and now i'm confused.

Comment: what would be the case if i'd like the same process to go backwards? I mean if i would like the array values to go like this- 0;4;3;2;1;0;4.... Will I need to use if statements or..? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I think `i--; i = i < 0 ? (length - 1) : i;` will do the trick. Of course `var i = length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function palabifunkcija(){
    i = (i+1) % bildes.length;
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').value= i;
    document.getElementById('PictureContent').style.background= bildes[i];    
}
```